# Prevent Entity Framework from creating foreign key in database

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a code-first database with the following POCOs:

```
public Foo {
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public Bar {
    public int BarId { get; set; }
    public virtual Foo DefaultFoo { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
}
```

This creates the following tables in the database:

**Foo**

```
FooId (PK, int, not null)
Bar_BarId (FK, int, null)
```

**Bar**

```
BarId (PK, int, not null)
DefaultFoo_FooID (FK, int, null)
```

**FooBar**

```
Bar_BarId (PK, FK, int, not null)
Foo_FooId (PK, FK, int, not null)
```

As you can see the `Foo` table gets a foreign key relation to the `Bar` table even if the `Foo` POCO does not have a one-to-one navigation property to the `Bar` POCO.

However, if I remove the `DefaultFoo` property from `Bar` this foreign key is removed.

And, if I leave `DefaultFoo` in, but remove `Bars` from `Foo` and `Foos` from `Bar` this foreign key is removed.

In other words, this foreign key is only present if *both* `DefaultFoo` and `Foos` is present on `Bar`.

How can I make Entity Framework *not* create this unneccessary foreign key (preferrably without using FluentApi)?

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to achieve? Having a Multiple- and Single- Foo property on Bar doesn't make sense to me.
Also, by giving Bar a property of type Foo, you DO make a one-to-one relation on those classes.

Comment: Could you try adding `public in SingleFooId{get;set}; ` in Bar class and decorate the navigational property `[ForeignKey("SingleFooId")]public virtual Foo SingleFoo { get; set; }`

Comment: @J.Swietek One `Bar`can have multiple `Foo`, but one of those `Foo`s is a default value. This is so that when there are many `Foo`s on a `Bar` you know which one to use if not specifically specified. I've edited the model to say Default instead of Single to (hopefully) make it a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is:

- Foo.Bar_BarId is for Bar.Foos
- Bar.DefaultFoo_FooId is for Bar.DefaultFoo
- FooBar table is for Foo.Bars

I do not/can not say why.

But For me you have to help de default behavior by using some configuration method: fluent or annotations to explicitly set the many/many relation.

You can challenge that by using linqpad and check the generated sql for some queries.

Answer (score 0):

I try your model and Junction table (FoosBars) is not created. The columns created is for the 2 1-many Foo.Bars and Bar.Foos properties and for the 1-1 Bar.DefaultFoo.

I think that in this case the only way is to configure n-m relationship using  HasMany/WithMany fluent API.
In this case EF works as expected.